# Convert string value to type

Tags: java, json, parsing, generics, gson

Say I have an object, and I'm storing all of it's attributes as pure JSON. Is there a way to store the .getClass() value in such a way as to be able to retrieve it and get the original object?

Ex:

```
class foo
{
int test;
String classType;
}


//other class
foo demo = new foo();
demo.classType = demo.getClass().toString();


//I'm not entirely sure how to convert classType into a type I can use to parse back the data, like so:
foo demo2 = (demo.classType)jsonData;
```

As this may be a bit of a broad question, I will accept an answer which just tells me what the above is called (a search term if you will).

Comment: Are you just trying to pass an object between processes/across a network? Have you looked into making an object Serializable?

Comment: Its being passed as part of a response object (as a payload), so I don't think I can use serializable.

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with using `Serializable` for payloads (though it has a lot of pain points that make it undesirable); [Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) is Google's solution to this problem, and [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) is another useful tool if you need to stick with JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [`Class.forName()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29), [`Class.getName()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName%28%29) and [`Class.newInstance()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance%28%29).

The code could be something like (not tested):

```
String className = foo.geClass().getName();

Class<?> cls = Class.forName(className);
Object newFoo = cls.newInstance();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `instanceof` operator to create and cast new created object to `foo`

```
    foo demo = new foo();
    demo.classType = demo.getClass().toString();

    foo demo2 = null;
    OtherClass demo3 = null;

        Class<?> clas=Class.forName(demo.getClass().getName());
        Object obj= clas.newInstance();
        if (obj instanceof foo) {
            demo2=(foo)obj;
        }else if (obj instanceof OtherClass) {
            demo3=(OtherClass)obj;
        }
```

Note : make sure if you use multiple else-if then add sub-classes condition on top and super classes after sub-classes and yes you need to add try-catch block too

Comment: With many classes, I will have many if clauses all doing a similar thing-meaning demo3=(OtherClass)obj; Is there a way to simplify this further? Ex: clas demo2=(clas)obj;

Comment: to use the specific function of some class you have to use downcasting .  you can directly use the casing but `if` condition  is there to cover uncertainty because let's just say the `clas.newInstance()` returns a `bar` and `foo demo2=(foo)obj` is an error and the other way would be using more and more reflection to find and call all methods of `foo` class

Answer (score 1):

Convert Java object to JSON

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Staff obj = new Staff();

//Object to JSON in file
mapper.writeValue(new File("c:\\file.json"), obj);

//Object to JSON in String
String jsonInString = mapper.writeValueAsString(obj);
```

Convert JSON to Java object

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String jsonInString = "{'name' : 'mkyong'}";

//JSON from file to Object
Staff obj = mapper.readValue(new File("c:\\file.json"), Staff.class);

//JSON from URL to Object
Staff obj = mapper.readValue(new URL("http://mkyong.com/api/staff.json"), Staff.class);

//JSON from String to Object
Staff obj = mapper.readValue(jsonInString, Staff.class);
```